# running two instances of gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, systemd

Trying to run two sites on gunicorn editing the service from

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

to

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/uganda_buzz

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/uganda_buzz/ug.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the logs shows the `ExecStart` can't be duplicated

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-122:~$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-02-14 09:36:52 EAT; 35s ago
 Main PID: 26150 (gunicorn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─26150 /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
           ├─26156 /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
           ├─26157 /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
           └─26160 /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26150] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26150] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock (26150)
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26150] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26156] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26156
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26157] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26157
Feb 14 09:36:52 ip-172-31-17-122 gunicorn[26150]: [2017-02-14 09:36:52 +0000] [26160] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26160
Feb 14 09:37:15 ip-172-31-17-122 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

what would be the best way to run two sites in this case, using the available configurations. Tried on the same line separated by space and comma each brings an error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`systemd` has great support for this situation. I presume you are running a web server like Nginx in front of the apps as a reverse proxy to route traffic to the right endpoint for each Gunicorn instance using their unique socket names. Here I'll focus on the `systemd` configuration.

It's desirable to be able to stop and start an individual `gunicorn` instance and also desirable to consider them as a `single service` that can be stopped or started together.

The `systemd` solution involves creating a "target" which will be used to treat both instances as a single service. Then, a single "template unit" will be used to allow you to add multiple gunicorns to the "target".

First, `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.target`:

```
# See README.md for more about this file
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn
Documentation=https://example.com/path/to/your/docs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That's it. You've created a target that when "enabled" will start at boot. Now `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn@.service`, the template file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
PartOf=gunicorn.target
# Since systemd 235 reloading target can pass through
ReloadPropagatedFrom=gunicorn.target


[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/%i

ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/%i/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=gunicorn.target
```

Notice the changes I made to your file:

1. Each instance is now `PartOf=` the target.
2. Enabling this service will make it boot as dependency of the target, due to an updated `WantedBy=`
3. The `WorkingDirectory=` and socket path now  use variables, because the file is now a template.

To start or stop all Gunicorn instances at once, we can simply:

```
systemctl start gunicorn.target
systemctl stop gunicorn.target
```

We can use `enable` and `disable` to add and remove new Gunicorn instances on the fly:

```
systemctl enable  gunicorn@kenyabuzz
systemctl disable gunicorn@ugandabuzz
```

We can also `stop` and `start` a specific service by itself:

```
systemctl start gunicorn@kenyabuzz
systemctl stop gunicorn@kenyabuzz
systemctl restart gunicorn@kenyabuzz
```

The original `gunicorn.service` file is no longer needed in this pattern and can be removed.

To  learn more about any of the system directives used, you can can look at `man systemd.directives`, which will list the specific man page that documents each directive.

Comment: what happens to the original `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`? I notice I have to create a gunicorn.target and a gunicorn@.service files in `/etc/systemd/system`

Comment: It is replaced by the two new files and no longer needed.

Comment: When I remove `gunicorn.service` and run `systemctl start gunicorn` I get: 

`Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`

Comment: Following the pattern above, `gunicorn.service` was replaced by `gunicorn.target`. So try `systemctl start gunicorn.target`. I've clarified the syntax in the answer. @LewyBlue

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I just wrote two seperate file - `gunicorn_live.service` and `gunicorn_staging.service` (with matching `.socket` files).  Then I can just use `systemctl start gunicorn_staging.socket`. If I ever need more than two services, I'll come back to this approach.

Comment: Also, I'm running gunicorn from the virtual environment of each project, so each service is running guncorn from a different location. I guess that would complicate this approach a bit

Comment: what is the difference in enable and start, or disable and stop?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sites, the logical solution would be for each one to be a different service. In this way you can restart one of them, or you can take down one of them for maintenance, without affecting the other.

Comment: I don't think it's possible or advised to have two gunicorn services running at the same time.

Comment: Of course it's possible and it has no problems. This is exactly what the answer you accepted does.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use supervisor.
Read the doc here; http://supervisord.org/