# Environment derived user for systemd

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, redhat, systemd

So I am trying to get a process to run under systemd using a user derived from the environment. Something like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf
Environment="NAME=%I"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/tomcat@%I
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start
ExecStop=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server stop
SuccessExitStatus=143
User=${TOMCAT_USER}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where `TOMCAT_USER` is defined in either `/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf` or the instance specific `/etc/sysconfig` file.

Obviously, the above doesn't work. And I'd prefer not to do a

```
su - ${TOMCAT_USER} -c /usr/libexec/tomcat/server start
```

If I can avoid it. What is the proper way of doing this in systemd.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running a group of similar apps. There's already an example of how to set this up at [running two instances of gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230370/254318)
.

The app being run is different, but the design with systemd would be the same.